# Shadow mapping from raster data

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, dem, time-series, shadow

I was wondering if anyone knows of a plugin, extension, process, etc. for mapping shadow locations based on date/time using raster data? I have searched and what I have been able to find all seems to require vectors or multipatch data. I have DSM rasters produced from LiDAR and would ultimately like to use those as the source for identifying locations of shadows, as I would like to the surrounding features in the raster to be used as sources of impact (i.e. trees). I am open to all options, but QGIS, Grass, and ArcGIS are preferred.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the QGIS/FOSS world, you can use the GRASS algorithm called **r.sunmask.datetime** from the Processing toolbox. You provide the date and time, and it creates a shadow mask.

Here's one, derived from Lidar data:-

[image]

Comment: Thank you Steven, that looks exactly like what I am looking for, I will give it a try. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: I am having issues with the command, it is throwing an error. I am choosing to use the date/time, but is seems to be asking for the sun position, etc. Thoughts?

     (Wed Jan 11 16:35:52 2017)                                                      
     r.sunmask --overwrite elevation=FDD4_ffl@solarLiDAR output=FDD4_ffl_shadow year=2017 month=1 day=11 hour=10 timezone=-5
     Using map center coordinates: 314000.000000 4841500.000000
     ERROR: Neither sun position nor east/north, date/time/timezone definition are complete
     (Wed Jan 11 16:35:52 2017) Command finished (0 sec)

Comment: did you use *r.sunmask.datetime*, or *r.sunmask*? Also, for *r.sunmask.datetime* I think you need to provide coordinates for a 'point of interest', e.g. a coordinate somewhere in your raster. You can use the 'copy coordinates' plugin for this (apologies, I think I forgot to mention this step)

Comment: I used r.sunmask, as I did not see r.sunmask.datetime as an option. I tried it by adding a position, but I am still getting an error: ERROR: Neither sun position nor east/north, date/time/timezone definition are complete

Comment: it's quite possible that *r.sunmask.datetime* was only added recently to the processing toolkit (i'm on qgis 2.18.1, and grass 7).

Comment: In QGIS, shadows can be modelled through a dedicated script (I'm the author...) : https://landscapearchaeology.org/2019/qgis-shadows/

Answer (score 3):

In ArcGIS the tool would be:

[Area Solar Radiation (Spatial Analyst > Solar Radiation)](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/area-solar-radiation.htm)

You could also do it in QGIS with the GRASS tool [r.sun](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass73/manuals/r.sun.html)

I used this tools to create several images along the day from which later I made a video. But now that I reread your question this may not be exactly what you want.

I think what you need is:
[r.sunmask.datetime or r.sunmask.position](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/r.sunmask.html)